# Simple data over sound solution

Tags: microcontroller, audio, microphone, mems

I'm designing an access control and I'm evaluating different technologies to make the device unlock the access.

One of the technologies I'm studying is integrating a microphpone in the device and sending an audio code based in a sequence of tones. The idea is the device to receive the audio sequence, process it and then confirm if the code is ok. In that case the device would unlock the access.

The current device has a MCU that is capable of using PDM microphones, so the idea is to use a PDM microphone for this purpose.

Given this information I would like to know of the MCU could be be capable of detecting a DTMF communication or if it needs additional HW.

Would there be another option or alternative so that the device could recognize a specific number using data over audio without using additional HW?

Comment: Wasn't there a movie in the US about that concept?  I think it only took 5 tones, though I haven't encountered it for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

> Given this information I would like to know of the MCU could be be capable of detecting a DTMF communication or if it needs additional HW.

PDM receiving is pretty easy, when you use timer/counter modules on your microcontroller for it, and have a DMA engine on it that allows your MCU's processor core to not be involved with it.

Detecting DTMF is "easy", as in that DTMF was designed with cheap digital logic as receivers in mind, in the late 1950s, early 1960s! So, yeah, DTMF works by sending two tones superimposed, one signifying the row, and one the column of your keypad, and you can decode them separately using cheap two-coefficient IIR filters.

Nothing, however, says that DTMF is a clever encoding for digital data and the easiest solution for your use case. Your microcontroller has the compute power of a complete 1963 telephone exchange building, and using a two-out-of-two-sets-of-four-tones method is *awkward* at best, and inefficient mathematically.

With your MCU being much more capable than before, you could simply do a 2-FSK transmission. Send a known preamble with which you correlate so your receiver knows when to start decoding bits. An ironically very simple method of doing a \$2^n\$-FSK system on a microcontroller is using an FFT as receiver (IFFT as transmitter) and having cyclic prefixes (repeat the end, say, quarter of each symbol before its beginning). That way you get easy synchronization, and you can use all frequencies at once, instead of just one-out-of-this-set-of-frequencies. You can then send arbitrary complex values on each frequency, separately. Sensibly, you'd start by sending either a -1 or +1.

This method also happens to be OFDM, which is a modern wireless communication scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this application note helpful: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an218.pdf

While that's targeted at the C8051F300, it describes an algorithm for efficient DTMF decoding that should be portable to most devices with adequate MIPS.

Something else you should consider: if you use tones in the audible range, then it's trivial for anyone with a smartphone or other recording device to carry out a replay attack.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning, for when the link dies, that the appnote refers to Goertzel algorithms for each tone.